# Jumping between two lines in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there a keyboard shortcut to jump between two lines in Sublime Text? Specifically, I want to be able to jump from the line with the cursor to the line that previously held the cursor. I am not looking to swap the lines, just to move the cursor between the two lines that last held the cursor.

There is an option in vim to use ``` `` ``` or `''` to jump between lines. I am looking for the exact same functionality but with Sublime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to Jump Back, and <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to Jump Forward

On Mac the commands are <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to Jump Back, and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to Jump Forward.

Comment: Sorry, had it backwards when I first posted. Fixed now.

Comment: This does not work for me on either Windows 7 or Server 2012 R2 with Sublime Text 2 or 3.

Comment: Ugh, I'm on a Mac, sorry. I'm sure there is some equivalent in the menus somewhere.

Comment: In the menu, these commands are labeled "Jump Back" and "Jump Forward".

Comment: On Windows this translates with "Jump Back" being `Alt+-` and "Jump Forward" is `Alt+Shift+-`. This works on Sublime Text 3. There does not appear to be a similar menu command or shortcut for Sublime Text 2.

Comment: Edited to match your discovery.